# Access VBA Object Required Error, referencing Field in a Table for IF statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting an object required error and because that is so horribly vague, I am having trouble fixing it.  I am trying to say: If the AssocID field is blank for this record, go through with the SQL statement, etc.  If it's not, display a MsgBox and go to the next record.  Here is my code.

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim mySQL As String
    GetID = Forms!frm_MainMenu!AssocIDBox
    CurRecord = Forms!frm_EC_All![Loan#].Value
    mySQL = "UPDATE tbl_Data SET tbl_Data.[AssocID] = " & GetID & " , tbl_Data.[tsStartAll] = Now WHERE tbl_Data.[Loan#] = " & CurRecord
    '
    '
    '
    If IsNull(tbl_Data.AssocID.Value) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL mySQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Me.TimerActivatedLabel.visible = True
        Me.Refresh
        ClaimedMsg = MsgBox("Loan has been assigned to you.", vbOKOnly, "Loan Assigned")
            If ClaimedMsg = vbOK Then
                DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Data SET tbl_Data.[tsHaveDocs] = Now WHERE tbl_Data.[Loan#] = " & CurRecord
                DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            End If
    Else
        AlreadyAssignedMsg = MsgBox("Loan has already been assigned.  Press OK to move to the next loan.", vbOKOnly, "Already Assigned!")
            If AlreadyAssignedMsg = vbOKOnly Then
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The error occurs on the If IsNull(etc) line.  I've looked at a lot of other stuff but it either didn't apply or I didn't really understand what they were talking about.  I'm still kind of a beginner.  Thanks!

Comment: whats is tbl_data? a form or table? as the error says, you can't reference a field in a table within IF statement. place a textbox bound it to that field and access that textbox. or if your form is bounded, use me.[fieldid]

Comment: I can't do that in this case and retain the functionality of this form, because I can't have the form refresh.  Can I reference a field in a query, rather than a table?

Comment: You need to use `MySQL` as the basis for a DAO recordset -- at least, that is the most common approach.  Then you need to retreive its values, which requires a different syntax than that used for form controls.  As far as I can tell, you need to learn about recordsets (and VBA trouble shooting, I might add).

Comment: @Smandoli are you serious? please don't give false answers!
msim.. i guess your form is bounded to the form. instead of tbl_data.Associd try me.[Associd]

Comment: I like kiks 73's answer.  On a side note though, you probably want to be careful with your `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` being at the top of your procedure and `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` being within an if statement that isn't always entered.  Since that means your warnings may not get turned back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for some strange reason, you don't have `tbl_Data.AssocID` field as a controlsource for a textbox in your form, you can do this:

```
...
' Declare a string variable and set it to the value of the field
' I concatenate an empty string to be sure to have not a null
Dim AssocID as string
AssocID = Dlookup("AssocID","tbl_Data","[Loan#] = " & CurRecord) & ""

' Test the string variable
If AssocID = "" Then
...
```

Comment: This works for my needs and I understand the logic behind it.  Thanks so much!!